# Visual Studio compiler compiles, but ReSharper shows compile errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, resharper

When I build (or rebuild) the solution with Visual Studio, there are no errors. However, ReSharper's *Errors in Solution* window shows errors such as "Cannot resolve symbol", "Cannot access private method here" or "Unexpected token".

Two files are affected. One is a `.cs` file and the other a `.designer.cs` file. They define the same class with `partial`. When I open the `.designer.cs` file in the Visual Studio editor, the errors disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the problems where due to an encoding problem. The `.designer.cs` file contained sequences such as `Ã¤`, `Ã¶` and `Ã¼`. I have changed them to the umlauts `ä`, `ö` and `ü`, respectively. That made the errors disappear.